# Where con Eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de traer los datos que esten entre unas fechas especificamente entre el mes indicado para hacerlo estaba tratando de la siguiente manera:

```
$ene = tbl_calibracion::where('cal_fechaCalibracion','>=','2019-01-01')
        ->where('cal_fechaCalibracion','<=','2019-01-31')
        ->where('cal_usu_id','=',$id)
        ->count();
```

Pero al fijarme en la ejecución, los datos que trae no son los correspondientes , en enero me deberia de salir 2, de acuerdo al `count` pero me trae 0. Como podria realizar esa consulta?

Las fechas se guardan así `2019-09-27 00:00:00` pero ese campo es `varchar` ya que en ese campo aveces no solo guarda fechas sino que tambien guardan texto

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos un registro de esa tabla para ver el formato de fechas

Comment: Así es el formato fecha de ese campo `2019-09-27 00:00:00`

Comment: Si es un string y exportas desde excel te recomiendo que el tipo de dato que no representa una fecha lo coloques en otro campo ya que tendrías conflicto con los formatos de fechas.

Comment: @JonathanOrta Estoy tratando de hacer eso pero como estoy importando desde un excel y en esa columna los datos son fechas y texto no logro hacerlo, hice otra publicacion a lo mejor puedas ayudarme https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/335922/importar-columna-que-contiene-fecha-y-texto-laravel-excel

Answer (score 0):

- Sustituye el uso del método `where` por el de `whereDate`
- Lo anterior hará que el valor de la columna se considere con una estructura de: **`YYYY-MM-DD`**
- Puedes opcionalmente quitar el símbolo de `=` del último `where`

Quedando así:

```
$ene = tbl_calibracion::whereDate('cal_fechaCalibracion','>=','2019-01-01')
                        ->whereDate('cal_fechaCalibracion','<=','2019-01-31')
                        ->where('cal_usu_id',$id)
                        ->count();
```

Comment: Probe el codigo y me cuenta todos los datos que tengo en mi `base de datos` no me toma directamente los de las fechas indicadas

Comment: Si, pues tengo 25 datos en mi base de datos, pero 6 de ellos tiene fecha en ese campo, los otros estan vacios. Al poner el codigo como de dijiste me trajo en enero 6 y pues deberia traer 2

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy importando desde un excel y necesito hacerlo así, pero en donde guardan la fecha tambien ponen por ejemplo 'excluido' etc...

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacer eso pero como estoy importando desde un excel y en esa columna los datos son fechas y texto no logro hacerlo, hice otra publicacion a lo mejor puedas ayudarme https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/335922/importar-columna-que-contiene-fecha-y-texto-laravel-excel