# Error al importar datos de excel a laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

**Hola** Estoy importando unos datos de un archivo de `excel` a mi base de datos en `Laravel`con la libreria `Laravel excel 3.1`, al momento de hacer un import me sale lo siguiente:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'cal_estado' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `tbl_calibracion` (`cal_certificado`, `cal_informeRechazo`, `cal_soliLabvantage`, `cal_informeResultado`, `cal_fechaCalibracion`, `cal_recepcion`, `cal_proximaCalibracion`, `cal_ins_id`, `cal_usu_id`) values (2019B-1514, NO TIENE, No Aplica, 0, 2019-09-27 00:00:00, OK, 2019-09-01 00:00:00, 1, 1))
```

El codigo que estoy usando para importar es el siguiente:

```
if ($row['fecha_de_calibracion'] == 'No Aplica' OR $row['fecha_de_calibracion'] == "") {
        $cal=$row['fecha_de_calibracion'];
        $fechaCal=NULL;
    }
    else{
        $cal=NULL;
        $fechaCal=\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['fecha_de_calibracion']);
    }


    return new tbl_calibracion([

        'cal_certificado'=>$row['certificado_de_calibracion'],
        'cal_informeRechazo'=>$row['consecutivo_de_rechazo'],
        'cal_soliLabvantage'=>$row['solicitud_de_servicio'],
        'cal_informeResultado'=>$row['informe_de_resultados'],
        'cal_estado'=>$cal,
        'cal_fechaCalibracion'=>$fechaCal,  
        'cal_recepcion'=>$row['recepcion_del_instrumento'],
        'cal_proximaCalibracion'=>$proximaCal,
        'cal_ins_id'=>$ins->ins_id,
        'cal_usu_id'=>$id,

    ]);
   }
```

Lo estoy haciendo de esa manera porque mi columna de excel "fecha de calibracion" contiene tanto fechas como texto. Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

El error que tenia era que no habia puesto `fillable` el campo `cal_estado`, al ponerlo fillable me salio perfectamente